# Python: List variable being passed as no type

Tags: python, list, types

Learning Python here, so sorry for any ignorance. Background - Assignment to make a tic tac toe game. Accomplished the goal, but trying to handle exceptions right now. At one point one of my variables is being passed with no type for some reason. The code in question is listed below `choice` is the variable in question and should be a list. The weird part is that it works as it should unless the user first chooses a spot on the board that has already been chosen and the failure then happens on the next iteration of the function.

```py
def user_choice():
    global board
    row_choice = 0
    column_choice = 0
    if player_1 == True:  # check whose turn
        print("Player 1, ")
    else:
        print("Player 2, ")
    while row_choice not in [1, 2, 3]:  # loop until input is correct
        row_choice = int(input("\tPlease select the row in which you would like to place your mark" +
                               " (1, 2, or 3 from top to bottom): "))
        if row_choice not in [1, 2, 3]:
            print("Sorry, you did not pick a valid number")
    while column_choice not in [1, 2, 3]:  # loop until input is correct
        column_choice = int(input("\tPlease select the column in which you would like to place your mark" +
                                  " (1, 2, or 3 from left to right): "))
        if column_choice not in [1, 2, 3]:
            print("Sorry you did not pick a valid number")
    choice = [(row_choice - 1), (column_choice - 1)]  # assign user input to list
    if board[choice[0]][choice[1]] != " ":  # checks to see if spot already has a mark in it
        print("Sorry, the other player has already picked that spot. Please pick another spot.")
        user_choice()
    else:
        # print(choice)
        # print(type(choice))
        return choice
```

I'm all about hearing other methods, but I would like to know what's happening here (in beginners terms please!)

If needed, the actual part of my code that is throwing the error is

```py
def update_board(choice):
    global board
    if player_1 == True:
        board[choice[0]][choice[1]] = 'X'  # replace nested list index with user input according to list passed
    else:
        board[choice[0]][choice[1]] = 'O'
```

```
board = [[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]



def game_on():
    answer = input("Ready to play (Y/N)? ").upper()
    if answer == "Y":
        while winner == " ":
            print_board()
            update_board(user_choice())
            test_win()
            change_player()
        game_over()
    elif answer == "N":
        print("No problem, run program again when you are ready.")
    else:
        print('Not a valid input. Please restart the program.')
```

EDIT: Fixed Indentation/added `board` variable/added main function `game_on` that drives games. sorry for poor terminology been trying to learn for all of 3 days now.

Comment: You need to fix your indentation; it's entirely unclear which parts of the code are in `user_choice` and which aren't.

Comment: What do you mean by "passed as no type"?  *Everything* has a type.

Comment: If the user chooses an already-taken spot, you recursively call `user_choice()` - and *throw away its return value*, implicitly returning None instead.

Comment: Don't use recursion to implement an open-ended loop. You are just asking for a `RecursionError`.

Comment: You also need to expand this to a [MCVE]; we have no idea where `board` comes from, and it could easily be the problem.

Comment: @chepner: In the case of reprompting until the user provides a valid input, it's not so bad; no user has the patience to make the hundreds of inputs required to blow the stack. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Well it's bad code that might not actually crash the program.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Fixed indentation - sorry, didn't check copy past accuracy.

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm using debug in PyCharm and it's telling me my `choice` variable is of NoType

Comment: @chepner Not much experience here, could you suggest another option other than recursion to restart the input inquiry ?

Comment: Use a loop instead of recursion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you don't return `user_choice()` in line 22 after you check if the spot is available or not. Right now you just run the function again, but you still return the `choice` variable, where the user had chosen a taken spot.

So to solve this, you should replace `user_choice()` with `return user_choice()` in the `user_choice` function.

Hope it works :)

Comment: This worked! I appreciate it, I'm just going to spend some time trying to understand exactly why it worked....and fixing all of my other problems :)